# How To Upload A File In IIS?

Tags: php, iis, file-upload

I'm trying to upload in IIS a php file but it fails, I don't know why.

I have found the following references:

[**Reference 1**](http://www.interactivetools.com/forum/forum-posts.php?postNum=2211143), 
[**Reference 2**](http://www.1ask2.com/TCExam/PHPUploadFile.html)

but still didn't found a proper step by step guide.

Any references is appreciable,

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by it's not getting uploaded on your IIS server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to check the permissions on the uploading directory. For more information chekc the following URL

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/fe6fc533-8688-4faf-848c-ba98cd6d6ec0/iis7-php-permissions-issue

Comment: i am changing the  c:\windows\temp permission to IIS_IUSRS.But it is not working.I don't know whether it is applied on the folder or not.But it is still not working sir.

Comment: you also need to change in the php.ini upload_tmp_dir
Can you check also upload_tmp_dir in phpinfo()

Comment: upload_tmp_dir is c:\windows\temp .when i am trying to upload the file.The summary is displaying like Upload: IMG0290A.jpg
Type: image/jpeg
Size: 7.5205078125 kB
Temp file: C:\Windows\Temp\php94CD.tmp
not stored

Comment: sir please help me i am new to iis.Even mkdir() is not working in iis help me sir.

Comment: Kindly check the php configuration again follow this tutorial 

[link](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php)